# Is the a way to pass multiple parameters in Angular using click()

Tags: angular, typescript

I would like to know if there is a way of passing parameters on click() in Angular.

```
      a  asp-action="CreateSales"  
      (click) = "CreateSales(productname='pa', price='16.5')" >

        Some Text

        </a>
```

I am new to Angular can anyone help?

Comment: remove the argument names, just pass the values/variables

Answer (score 0):

Just use the variables in html:

```
<a (click)="CreateSales(param1, param2, param3)">Some Text</a>
```

for example

```
<a (click)="CreateSales(1, 'hello', 'world')">Some Text</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use it like:

```
<a (click)="CreateSales(param1, param2, param3)">Some Text</a>
```